# Using Perfmon to determine which service consuming all CPU

Tags: windows, sql-server

I have written a windows based webserver service which uses Sql Server Express as the back-end database.  Every couple days CPU will spike to 100%.  Inspection of my webserver logs reveal my service was having problems making queries to the Sql Server database .  When I examine Task Manager, both my service and Sql Server are using the majority of the CPU.  I am unsure if the problem is my service or Sql Server.

I was hoping to use PerfMon or some other utility to keep a log of CPU usage by process (or filter specifically my service and Sql Server).  This way when my server enters this state I can go back, inspect these logs, and determine if it was my service or Sql Server which initially caused the CPU spike.

Is this possible?

[This article](https://serverfault.com/questions/324588/monitoring-services-using-perfmon) indicates PerfMon cannot be used to track metrics for a specific service.

Comment: have you tried WPR/WPA?

Answer (score 0):

To analyze the CPU usage on modern Windows systems (NT6.x - Vista or newer), you can use the [Windows Performance Toolkit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh162945.aspx).

Install the WPT, which is part of the [Windows 10 SDK](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk) (make sure you use the TH2 Version of the SDK if you capture a trace on Win7/8, the TH1 version from July is broken).

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance
>   Toolkit\wpr.exe" -start CPU -start DotNET  && timeout -1 &&
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance
>   Toolkit\wpr.exe" -stop Result.etl

Now open the `result.etl` in Windows Performance Analyzer (WPA.exe) and [analyze the CPU usage](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis)

[image]

Here the CPU usage comes from simply starting [Reflector](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/).